# Show that a set admits a tangent plane

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f: \mathbb R^3\rightarrow \mathbb R, g:\mathbb R^2\rightarrow \mathbb R$ be differentiable functions with $f(x,y,z)=g(xy,yz)$ and suppose that $g(u,v) $   satisfies $g(2,6)=2, g_u(2,6)=-1, g_v(2,6)=3$.

Show that  $f^{-1}(2)$ admits a tangent plane at  $(1,2,3)$ and find an equation for it.

First off, what does it mean that a set "admits" a tangent plane? What definition of a tangent plane should I use? (This problem isn't part of any course, so there isn't any "default definition". I know that for manifolds in $\mathbb R^n$ the tangent plane at a point $x$ is the image of the differential at $x$ of any local parametrization at $x$.) Any help?

Comment: “Admits a tangent plane at...” here means “a tangent plane to the set exists at...”

Answer (score 1):

You are being asked to show that there is a well-defined tangent plane to the level surface $f(x,y,z)=2$ at the point $(1,2,3)$ and to find its equation. Implicit in this question is that $f(1,2,3)=2$. The former is pretty much a given since you’re told that both $f$ and $g$ are differentiable. To find the equation of the tangent plane, use the fact that the gradient of a function is normal to its level surfaces. You’ll need to use the chain rule to compute this gradient.

Comment: But to show that there is a well-defined tangent plane, I should know the definition of a tangent plane, right?. What definition am I supposed to use?

Comment: @Cary Pick one that’s related to differentiability of functions at a point, since you’re going to end up using the differentiability of $f$, $g$ and the unnamed function that maps $(x,y,z)\mapsto (xy,yz)$. “The plane that best approximates the surface near a point” seems most convenient to me since that ties directly into the definition of the differential of a function.

Comment: I’m going to revise my comment a bit: use the definition of a tangent plane that’s used by the text/web site/whatever that’s the source of this exercise.